# Unknown user name in Internet Explorer properties

Tags: windows-7, windows

In my Internet Explorer Properties Security box in the section Group or user names I found. Account Unknown(S-1-5-80-2375682873-768044350=35334…
What is this?

Answer (score 0):

[It means one of two things](http://windowsitpro.com/security/determining-if-sid-deleted-user-or-group).

- First, the user or group might have been deleted. When you delete a user or group, Windows can’t check the ACL of every object on every computer of the local domain and all trusted domains for the access control entries (ACEs) assigned to the user or group and delete such ACEs. Therefore, you end up with “orphaned” ACEs, which aren't a threat to security.
- The other possibility is that the user or group still exists but the computer was unable to connect to the appropriate domain controller (DC) to resolve the SID's name because of network problems, a failed trust relationship, or because a DC is down.

The first possibility applicable as well to a computer out of an Active Directory Domain.